# User get confirm dialogue box when user navigate from the current Page in GWTP

Tags: gwt, smartgwt, uibinder, gwt-rpc, gwt2

User need to get the confirm dialogue or want to send some backend message like am leaving from the page in GWTP.

In GWT-P there is no specific widget or event handler available for to check the widget is going out of focus from the user screen.

Is there any default widget or event handler for to check the widget or view page get out of focus means user navigating current page to another page.

Your help much appreciated!!

Comment: Take a look here: http://www.gwtproject.org/doc/latest/DevGuideMvpActivitiesAndPlaces.html you are looking for something like the mayStop method of an activity.

Comment: You are correct Hoss. Can you pls me through the any sample example if possible.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention. I am using GWT-P not normal GWT

Comment: Take a look here: https://code.google.com/p/gwt-platform/wiki/GettingStarted#Navigation_confirmation